# How To Create new Date JavaScript without DayLight Applied

Tags: javascript, timezone

I am doing

```
new Date('2023-03-12T02:00:00')
```

... in Pecific TimeZone I am getting

> Sun Mar 12 2023 03:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

meanwhile when I am doing

```
new Date('2023-03-13T02:00:00')
```

> Mon Mar 13 2023 02:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

if it is due to daylight then why it is not on 13 March which is also daylight applied date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Daylight Saving Time in United States](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa) starts on Sun, Mar 12, 2023 2:00 AM:

> When local standard time is about to reach
> Sunday, 12 March 2023, 02:00:00 clocks are turned forward 1 hour to
> Sunday, 12 March 2023, 03:00:00 local daylight time instead.

That means that your local time `2023-03-12T02:00:00` does not exist. JavaScript is designed to try really hard when parsing dates, some times too hard:

```
> console.log(new Date("2023-02-31"));
2023-03-03T00:00:00.000Z
```

In this case it applies a correction that kind of makes sense: when clock reaches 2:00 it moves forward to 3:00, just as US legislation mandates.

- If your use case requires local times, you must be aware that there's a whole hour that's skipped every year and another hour (when DST ends) that runs twice in a row (albeit in different time zones).
- If your use case requires absolute times, you can use UTC for all your calculations and convert to local time zone on display, should that be needed.

Comment: I can't get it for UTC. I have events created in Db they contain the timezone that they are created. and I need to convert them to the user time from which they are created. also, I have a calendar view that already takes the event date in UTC. in UTC it is also behaving the same.

Comment: the problem is with 2 AM only. because when I have event date of 2 AM it converts to 3 Am while creating a new Date on 12 March the day daylight changes. other is when I have the event at 9 AM. when I convert this to UTC. and user Date.setHorus(2) then it also converts the date from 2 AM to 3 AM. because I am in pecific and it is -7 at 12 March 9 AM.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because you have accepted my answer and you've then added comments repeating the information from the question. The problem is not just 2:00, it's the whole hour: 2:01, 2:02, 2:03... You can't set an appointment on March 12 2023 02:30:00 Pacific Time more than you can set it on February 31st or August 40th.

Comment: your answer is correct when daylight starts it is definitely applied daylight for the date which is not in daylight. I have checked with other time zones where daylight starts at 5:00 AM similar problem is there it must be handled using UTC. but for me, it will be an extra conversion first from event timezone to UTC then from UTC to user timezone. In the same way if I am converting the 8 AM to 1 AM using -7 it is not setting 1 AM it is setting 12 AM. because it is -8